# How to save data from a "For Loop" into a compressed ".txt" file

Tags: java, zip, compression

I am trying to write a java code to save data from a "For Loop" (2d array named "arr") into a compressed ".txt" file.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path to zip file);
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(path txt file);
zipOut.putNextEntry(ze);
for (int r = 0; r < 1048577; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 25; c++) {
        zipOut.write(arr[r][c] + ","); // how do I write this line?
    }

    zipOut.write("\n"); // how do I write this line?
}

zipOut.closeEntry();
zipOut.close();
```

What piece of code should be added to convert the result into Bytes and then use "ZipOutputStream" to write data into a compressed ".txt" file?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your array?  `String[][]`?

Comment: It's Int[][]  and I need to insert a comma between each element.

Comment: Ok, why not write the data to a file and then compress it?

Comment: I would like to avoid creating an uncompressed txt file and then read it again to create a compressed txt file (it would take an extra time).

Comment: So you want the `int`s rendered to Strings? i.e. a value of 10,234 becomes "10234"?

Comment: @tgdavies, Yes, I need the `int`s rendered to Strings. The compressed text file will be filled with many numbers, all separated from each other by commas (like a csv file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = null;
        ZipEntry ze = null;
        try {
            char[][] arr = {{'a', 'b'}, {'d', 'c'}};
            fos = new FileOutputStream("a.zip");
            zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos));
            ze = new ZipEntry("out.txt");
            zipOut.putNextEntry(ze);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int r = 0; r < arr.length; r++) {
                for (int c = 0; c < arr[0].length; c++) {
                    sb.append(arr[r][c]).append(",");
                }

                sb.append("\n"); // how do I write this line?
            }
            zipOut.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
            zipOut.closeEntry();
            zipOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

maybe this is useful for you

Comment: arr is an ´int[][]´ array, filled with numbers. How could ´char[][] arr´ be changed to ´int[][] arr´ ?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right (the ´append´ method accepts an ´int´). I have just tested the code and it returned an OutOfMemoryError, as array "arr" is very big (26,214,400 lines by 25 columns). How could this problem be solved?

Comment: @user16320675 made a suggestion that ended up solving the "OutOfMemoryError" exception.

Answer (score 1):

So, my "big" concern is in how you might "read" the data back in, writing it is actually relatively easy.

The following does a "basic" job, using a couple of `StringJoiners` to produce a `String` which can be written to the file and the a, somewhat, convoluted process to decompress it.

The problem here is, the limiting factor (for me at least), is the fact that you need to read the entire contents of the file before you can begin reconstructing it.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
        File targetFile = new File("Test.dat");

        int[][] data = new int[][]{
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
        };

        StringJoiner outterJoiner = new StringJoiner("\n");
        for (int[] outter : data) {
            StringJoiner innerJoiner = new StringJoiner(",");
            for (int value : outter) {
                innerJoiner.add(Integer.toString(value));
            }
            outterJoiner.add(innerJoiner.toString());
        }

        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile))) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("master");
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            zos.write(outterJoiner.toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(targetFile)); ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
            if (zipEntry != null) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                String contents = new String(baos.toByteArray());
                System.out.println(contents);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if, instead of relying on `\n` as a delimiter, you used the `ZipEntry` instead, this would allow you to process each individual "line" of data at a time...

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
        File targetFile = new File("Test.dat");

        int[][] data = new int[][]{
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
        };

        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile))) {
            for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
                int[] values = data[index];
                ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("Values-" + index);
                zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
                for (int value : values) {
                    joiner.add(Integer.toString(value));
                }
                zos.write(joiner.toString().getBytes());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(targetFile))) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = null;
            while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
                try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead = -1;
                    while ((bytesRead = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                    String contents = new String(baos.toByteArray());
                    System.out.println(contents);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints out...

```
Values-0
0,1,2,3,4,5
Values-1
6,7,8,9,10,11
```

Now, obviously, you might not know how many lines you need, where as the first example, a simple `String#split` will tell you.  (You could pre-read each entry, but that's double dipping)

> is it possible to have ZipOutputStream save "contents" into a compressed ".txt" file called "Compressed file.txt" in a zip file "C:/Users/Username/Documents/Compressed folder.zip" ?

That's entirely up to you, if you're not concerned about reading/parse the file again, then the process can be greatly reduced (in effort and complexity).

So, the example below will write a line of content at time, so you're only ever creating a single line of text and then writing it to the `ZipEntry`.  The `StringJoiner` makes this process SOOOO much simpler

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DataFormatException {
        File targetFile = new File("Compressed.zip");

        int[][] data = new int[][]{
            {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
            {6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}
        };

        try (ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile))) {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry("Compressed.txt");
            zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
            for (int[] outter : data) {
                StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",", "", "\n");
                for (int value : outter) {
                    joiner.add(Integer.toString(value));
                }
                zos.write(joiner.toString().getBytes());
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to have ZipOutputStream save "contents" into a compressed ".txt" file called "Compressed file.txt" in a zip file "C:/Users/Username/Documents/Compressed folder.zip" ?

Comment: That's up to you, change the `ZipEntry` to what ever name you want.  My issue is I don't see that you're actually saving your self a lot of time by going this particular route, but that's me

Answer (score 1):

Here a very basic/simplyfied *idea*:

```java
var zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("text.zip"));
try (zos) {
    var entry = new ZipEntry("test.txt");
    zos.putNextEntry(entry);

    var value = 12345; // just an example, should come from array/loop
    
    zos.write(Integer.toString(value).getBytes());
    zos.write(",".getBytes());
    
    zos.write("\n".getBytes());
    
    zos.closeEntry();
}
```

you'll need to add the loop.

Note1: use variables/constants for `",".getBytes(...)` and `"\n"...`
Note2: using the default system charset for `getBytes()`, to use a specific one, use something like `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: I have 2 java codes: one to create a ".txt" file (size 3GB). It takes 1 min. 8 sec. to create this ".txt" file. And the other code to compress this ".txt" file. It takes 54 sec. to create a new compressed ".txt" file. As I need to create more than 10,000 compressed ".txt" files, I am trying to make the first code create compressed files and avoid losing 54 seconds with the second code. I applied the ideia shown in this answer to the first code, but it took 7min. 37sec. to create a compressed ".txt" file. The same code creates an uncompressed file in less time. Is it possible to make it faster?